# Move uploaded file error beacuase array is given

Tags: php

Im getting the error below:

> Warning: move_uploaded_file() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Whats wrong with the move function? I have to use it, right?

```
$target_path = "../docs/"; 
    if(isset($_FILES['doc_file']))
    {
        foreach($_FILES['doc_file']["name"] AS $key=>$file)
        {
            if($_FILES['doc_file']['size'][$key]  != 0 )
            {
                $doc_nev = mysqli_real_escape_string($kapcs, $_POST["doc_nev"][ $key ] );
                $file = $_FILES['doc_file']['name'][$key];
                $file_name = basename($file);

                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['doc_file']['tmp_name'], $target_path))
                {
                    mysqli_query($kapcs, "INSERT INTO doc(doc_nev, doc_file, tananyag_id) 
                    VALUES('".$doc_nev."','".$file_name."', '".$id."')") or die(mysqli_error($kapcs));

                    header("Location: szerkesztes_tananyag.php?cat=".$page_now."&id=".$id."&new-file=1");
                }
                else
                {
                    $error[] = "A dokumentum mentése nem sikerült, próbálja újra.";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $error[] = "Nincs kiválasztva fájl 2.";
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $error[] = "Nincs kiválasztva fájl 1.";
    }
```

Comment: why you delete that question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41197683/change-an-i-element-class-on-click-jquery/41197699#41197699

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like you do with the other array elements, you need to use the `$key`.  Also add a filename to the path `$target_path . $file`:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['doc_file']['tmp_name'][$key], $target_path . $file))
```

Comment: I added that. But if i get out the if() from the move_uploaded_file, it works. Whit, if, it gets error.

arning: move_uploaded_file(): The second argument to copy() function cannot be a directory in

Comment: Edited... You have to give it a file name.